# How to list all data types from a cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I create a PowerShell cmdlet which contains one command, which is going to use below data structure

```cs
public class DataContract
{
    public string DataName;
    public int Value;
}
```

I want to know after `Import-Module <path of dll>`, how could I use some PowerShell commands to list all public data types like above `DataContract` in my home-made Cmdlet?

I have tried `Get-Command`, but it could only list all commands, without public data types.

Comment: `(Get-Command YourCmdlet).ImplementingType.Assembly.ExportedTypes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @PetSerAl!

The command working for me is `(Get-Command -Module YourCmdlet).ImplementingType.Assembly.ExportedTypes`